# How to call a service in view model through the interface

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

- I have defined a service `RestService.cs` and trying to call the
  service from the view model `FirstViewModel.cs`
- How to achieve this using `IntIRestService.cs`

**RestService.cs**

```
namespace SqliteDemo.core.Services
{
    public class RestService : IntIRestService
    {
        public async Task<List<People>> GetSalesPeopleAsync()
        {
            try
            {   
                //Declare a Http client
                var client = new HttpClient();
                //Add a Base URl
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.MUrl);
                //Add the response type
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //Add the API
                var response = await client.GetAsync("iCodersLab/Custom-ListView-Using-Volley/master/richman.json");

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //return content;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var t = ex.Message;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstViewModel.cs**

```
namespace SqliteDemo.core.ViewModels
{
    public class FirstViewModel 
        : MvxViewModel
    {
        public event EventHandler mNetworkClick;

        public ICommand networkTask
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public FirstViewModel()
        {
            networkTask = new MvxCommand<string>(param =>
            {
                //Calling Service here
            });
        }

    }
}
```

**IntIRestService.cs**

```
namespace SqliteDemo.core.Services.ServiceInterfeces
{
    public interface IntIRestService
    {
        Task<List<People>> GetSalesPeopleAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntIrestService is the interface, you can't instantiate the interface.
You need to instantiate the concrete class that implements the interface.

```
IntIrestService intIrestService = new RestService();
```

Comment: Thank you , 

`intIrestService.GetSalesPeopleAsync();` I can use to call the Service, How to get the control back to view model once the async task is completed (In android we use listeners, How to do the same here)